# Cannot serve static image via Slim in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I'm trying to serve an image. My image is located in public folder. I'm using this syntax:

```
img src="picture.png"/
```

But that won't show an image, but displays an error instead:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/reviews/4/skills/3/tests/picture.png"
Rails.root: /Users/Greg/Projects/employee-rating
```

How can I serve it right?

Comment: Can you give more context to this view?

Usually assets are stored under `app/assets/images` and are linked with the `image_tag` helper.

You can read more on that here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Comment: Bingo, that one works: = image_tag "picture.png"